# Why is my code redirecting the page when I submit the form via AJAX?

Tags: python, django, ajax

[image][image]My problem is well described in the title, so I'll leave the code below

This is the HTML: (Sorry for the indentation but I don't often use Stackoverflow)

```
    {% block content %}
    <div class="col-8 mt-5">
        <form id="createTaskForm" class="form-inline justify-content-center" method="post" date-url="{% url 'task_list' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="mx-3">
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            
            <button id="createButton" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                create
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 mt-5" id="taskList">
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <div class="card mb-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ task.title }}
                    <button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#createButton').click(function(){
        var serializedData = $('#createTaskForm').serialize()
        
        $ajax({
            url: $("#createTaskForm").data('url'),
            data: serializedData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                $("#taskList").append('<div class="card mb-1"><div class="card-body">' + response.task.title + '<button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>')
            }
        })
    });

});
```

And finally the view from Django:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View

from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm

from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class TaskList(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = TaskForm()
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'task/task_list.html', context={'form':form, 'tasks':tasks})

    def post(self, request):
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_task = form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'task': model_to_dict(new_task)}, status=200)
        else:
            return redirect('task_list')
```

Hope to get a response soon, I'd be so grateful to have a explanation

Comment: it need end up with return false in the click function to omit redirecting to json page

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: $('#createButton').click(function(){ //your codes; return false; });

Comment: Didn't work, anyway thanks

Comment: one more bug. you need put button tag element out of form tag element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT NUMBER 2:**

Try updating your JQuery ajax code to this as it appears you are using the old way in your code:

```
var serializedData = $('#createTaskForm').serialize();
$.ajax({ url: '{% url 'task_list' %}',
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         data: serializedData,
         cache: false
       }).done(function(response) {
         $("#taskList").append('<div class="card mb-1"><div class="card-body">' + response.task.title + '<button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>')
       });
```

**EDIT:**

In your form, you are assigning the data-url to the url in ajax, however, you spelled data-url "date-url" so it will return empty every time. Not only that, but your form is posting before the Ajax can even be run. Try this:

javascript:

```
 function createTask(){
        var serializedData = $('#createTaskForm').serialize()

        $ajax({
            url: '{% url 'task_list' %}',
            data: serializedData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                $("#taskList").append('<div class="card mb-1"><div class="card-body">' + response.task.title + '<button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>')
            }
    });
 }
```

In your template, just use:

```
<form id="createTaskForm" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="mx-3">
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            
            <button id="createButton" onclick="createTask()" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                create
            </button>
        </form>
```

**PREVIOUS RESPONSE:**

It appears in your post that you are returning a fully rendered page if the form validation fails, instead of JSON. You could try something like this to see what you are getting:

```
def post(self, request):
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_task = form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'task': model_to_dict(new_task)}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'task': None}, status=400)
```

You can't "redirect" a javascript AJAX request from the Django backend, you have to handle that in the template.

It's hard to tell if that is what you are referring to in the title. If you clarify it I will update my answer.

Comment: What I meant is that i'm getting a JSON page when I hit the create button. Is there any way to stay in the same page without getting a JSON page?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "JSON page"

Comment: "{"task": {"id": xx, "title": "xx", "complete": false}}"  a page like this comes up every time I create a task

Comment: And what is wrong with that? It is the JSON response that is returned by the JsonResponse. Please post a screenshot of what you mean.

Comment: Can I avoid getting it?

Comment: And instead  stay in the actual page

Comment: Then you wouldn't have any data in your AJAX to do anything with. Please post a screenshot of what you mean, it isn't clear.

Comment: I added two pics

Comment: Instead of show me that first image, how can I handle it to stay in the page?

Comment: Where does that first image show up? Is your AJAX function appending it to your page? When you click the button, what happens?

Comment: When i clicked the button, it redirect me to the first image

Comment: I append the AJAX function to my card html

Comment: And I think that being redirected to that page is not the best option...

Comment: I understand now. I've updated my answer, see if that works. The problem is that your form is submitting before the AJAX can even be called, and your URL is blank because of a typo - you put "date-url" instead of "data-url"

Comment: Well, what is it doing? Any errors? I don't know what "didn't work out" means. Did you fix the typo?

Comment: Yes I fixed it.  but it is still redirecting me to the other page

Comment: Why did you use 'request.task.title'  when you're passing data as an argument?

Comment: That was a typo on my part. It is fixed.

Comment: Still get the same... i don't want to be annoying dude

Comment: I get it...the problem is that your form is submitting before the AJAX is triggering, so it is sending the user to the part of your view that only renders a JSON response, you just have to figure out why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

#### first way: to fix submit js, and drop click function for createButton button.

```
<form>
//pass
<input id='id_submit' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value="submit"/>
</form>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#createTaskForm').on('submit', function(e){
    $.ajax({//pass
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

#### second way: put createButton button out of form tag, and fire submit by click function of button.

```
<form>
//pass
</form>
<button id='id_submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_submit').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({//pass
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for so long. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after two days I found a solution. This is the one that is working for me. here is the code...

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#createTaskForm').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var dataSerialized = $('#createTaskForm').serialize()
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: $('#createTaskForm').data('url'),
            data: dataSerialized,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                $('#taskList').append(
                    '<div class="card mb-1"><div class="card-body">' + response.task.title + '<button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>'
                )
            }
        });

    });

});
```

HTML

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-8 mt-5">
        <form id="createTaskForm" class="form-inline justify-content-center" method="POST" data-url="{% url 'task_list' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="mx-3">
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <input id='id_submit' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value="submit"/>
        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-5 mt-5" id="taskList">
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <div class="card mb-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ task.title }}
                    <button type="button" class="close float-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Hope it can be helpful for future questions.